# Out of space due to wal files

Tags: postgresql

Over the weekend, my postgresql server stopped functioning. After some troubleshooting I realized that I am out of space on a 1 TB drive. Is there a way for me to recover from this?

- I have no space to temporarily move the files. Are any of them safe to delete?
- The logical replication is set up using Postgresql 10 - can I tweak these settings to prevent this from happening again?

> /pg_replslot = 395 GB
>
> /pg_wal = 283 GB

```
 - Settings -

wal_level = logical                     # minimal, replica, or logical
                                        # (change requires restart)
#fsync = on                             # flush data to disk for crash safety
                                                # (turning this off can cause
                                                # unrecoverable data corruption)
#synchronous_commit = on                # synchronization level;
                                        # off, local, remote_write, remote_apply, or on
#wal_sync_method = fsync                # the default is the first option
                                        # supported by the operating system:
                                        #   open_datasync
                                        #   fdatasync (default on Linux)
                                        #   fsync
                                        #   fsync_writethrough
                                        #   open_sync
#full_page_writes = on                  # recover from partial page writes
#wal_compression = off                  # enable compression of full-page writes
#wal_log_hints = off                    # also do full page writes of non-critical updates
                                        # (change requires restart)
wal_buffers = 16MB                      # min 32kB, -1 sets based on shared_buffers
                                        # (change requires restart)
#wal_writer_delay = 200ms               # 1-10000 milliseconds
#wal_writer_flush_after = 1MB           # measured in pages, 0 disables

#commit_delay = 0                       # range 0-100000, in microseconds
#commit_siblings = 5                    # range 1-1000

# - Checkpoints -

checkpoint_timeout = 40min # range 30s-1d
max_wal_size = 6GB
min_wal_size = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9 # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
#checkpoint_flush_after = 256kB         # measured in pages, 0 disables
#checkpoint_warning = 30s               # 0 disables


# - Sending Server(s) -

# Set these on the master and on any standby that will send replication data.

max_wal_senders = 3             # max number of walsender processes
                                # (change requires restart)
#wal_keep_segments = 0          # in logfile segments, 16MB each; 0 disables
#wal_sender_timeout = 60s       # in milliseconds; 0 disables

max_replication_slots = 4       # max number of replication slots
```

Comment: Did you configure any replication slots? "pg_replslot = 395 GB" seems to indicate you created a replication slot, but you have no slave that consumes the WAL segments

Comment: Yes, I have a local machine which is subscribed to the database. This has worked since October 10th of this year. All the data I want available on the local machine has been available, so I did not look into it too much though. Is that a safe folder to delete for now? Perhaps there was a network issue or something which prevented the replication server from grabbing the data from the primary server?

Comment: FYI - I checked the replication server and the replication stopped apparently at some point. There is an active subscription still in pg_stat_subscription but I guess data has not been sent. This is a non-critical replication. Is it safe to delete the pg_replslot folder for now and turn off logical replication?

Comment: You should delete the replication slot, not the folder, e.g. through pg_drop_replication_slot() https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-REPLICATION

Comment: Whew. I had to delete some files to turn on the server using systemctl postgresql@10-main, but then I was able to drop the replication slot and it immediately freed up some space. Can you post an answer so I can accept it? Also, is there anything I need/should do with the large pg_wal folder?

Comment: Also - perhaps this deserves a new question - I checked the log files on the subscriber and I saw that it was continually failing to replicate because of a primary key failure (which should not be the case because the master server does not have duplicates...), and then the errors were about there being no space so the XID failed. That server has 9 TB of space, so there truly should be no issues about writing wal files